# weather prediction using tkinter

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, joblib, geocoder

the code as follows
this code is for a weather prediction project using tkinter

i was trying to run this code in vs code after downloading necessary libraries like scikit- learn, numpy,pandas,geocoder and pillow . but in running the code multiple times even in the conda environment i am getting errors...

the errors have been shown after  the code here ..

what am i supposed to do now

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import joblib
from tkinter.font import Font
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import geocoder
from datetime import datetime

classifier = joblib.load('dtm.joblib')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Weather")
window.geometry("700x580")
window.configure(bg="#396285")

def predict_weather(event=None):
    precipitation = float(entry_precipitation.get())
    temp_max = float(entry_temp_max.get())
    temp_min = float(entry_temp_min.get())
    wind = float(entry_wind.get())

    if wind > 15:
        messagebox.showwarning("Alert", "Cyclone Alert: Heavy wind \n National Disaster Response Force (NDRF): 011-26107953")
    elif precipitation > 10:
        messagebox.showwarning("Alert", "Flood Alert: Heavy precipitation (cm) \n National Emergency Response Center (NERC): 011-26701728, 011-26701729")
    elif temp_max < -5:
        messagebox.showwarning("Alert", "Heavy Snowfall Alert: Very Low Temperature (°C) \n Tip: Stay Away from Remote Locations")
    elif temp_min > 38:
        messagebox.showwarning("Alert", "Drought Alert: Very High temperature (°C) \n Tip: Save Enough Water, don't waste it")
    else:
        prediction = classifier.predict([[precipitation, temp_max, temp_min, wind]])
        label_result.configure(text="                    Predicted weather for today is  " + prediction[0], font=("Helvetica", 20), justify="center")

def update_time():
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M %p")
    current_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d %B %Y")
    current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")
    label_datetime.config(text=f"{current_time}\n{current_date}\n{current_day}")
    window.after(1000, update_time)

heading_font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=20, weight="bold")
label_title = tk.Label(window, text="WEATHER FORECAST AND ALERT SYSTEM", font=heading_font, bg="#396285", fg="white")
label_title.pack(pady=(10, 20))

frame_inputs = tk.Frame(window, bg="#396285")
frame_inputs.pack(padx=50, pady=20, anchor="w")

label_font = Font(family="Helvetica", size=14, weight="bold")

label_precipitation = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="Precipitation", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_precipitation.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, sticky="w")
entry_precipitation = tk.Entry(frame_inputs)
entry_precipitation.grid(row=0, column=1)
label_unit_precipitation = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="cm", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_unit_precipitation.grid(row=0, column=2)
entry_precipitation.bind('<Return>', lambda e: entry_temp_max.focus())

label_temp_max = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="Maximum Temperature", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_temp_max.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, sticky="w")
entry_temp_max = tk.Entry(frame_inputs)
entry_temp_max.grid(row=1, column=1)
label_unit_temp_max = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="°C", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_unit_temp_max.grid(row=1, column=2)
entry_temp_max.bind('<Return>', lambda e: entry_temp_min.focus())

label_temp_min = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="Minimum Temperature", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_temp_min.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, sticky="w")
entry_temp_min = tk.Entry(frame_inputs)
entry_temp_min.grid(row=2, column=1)
label_unit_temp_min = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="°C", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_unit_temp_min.grid(row=2, column=2)
entry_temp_min.bind('<Return>', lambda e: entry_wind.focus())

label_wind = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="Wind Speed", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_wind.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, sticky="w")
entry_wind = tk.Entry(frame_inputs)
entry_wind.grid(row=3, column=1)
label_unit_wind = tk.Label(frame_inputs, text="mph", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=label_font)
label_unit_wind.grid(row=3, column=2)
entry_wind.bind('<Return>', predict_weather)

predict_image = Image.open("predict.png")
predict_image = predict_image.resize((150, 50), Image.LANCZOS)
predict_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(predict_image)

button_predict = tk.Button(window, image=predict_photo, command=predict_weather, bd=0, bg="#396285", activebackground="#396285")
button_predict.pack(pady=(0, 20), anchor="w", padx=155)

label_result = tk.Label(window, text="", bg="#396285", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 12, "bold"), justify="center")
label_result.pack(anchor="w")

frame_black = tk.Frame(window, bg="black", height=250)
frame_black.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

g = geocoder.ip('me')

country = g.country

if country == 'IN':
    country = 'India'
current_location = g.city + ', ' + country

label_location = tk.Label(frame_black, text=current_location, bg="black", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 36, "bold", "italic"))
label_location.pack(side="top", padx=(60, 0), pady=(0, 4))

label_datetime = tk.Label(frame_black, text="", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Helvetica", 35))
label_datetime.pack(side="top", pady=(0, 20))

update_time()

window.mainloop()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\nanda\Desktop\Weather-Prediction-main\Weather-Prediction-main\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    classifier = joblib.load('dtm.joblib')
  File "C:\Users\nanda\.vscode\New folder\envs\my\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "C:\Users\nanda\.vscode\New folder\envs\my\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "C:\Users\nanda\.vscode\New folder\envs\my\lib\pickle.py", line 1212, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "C:\Users\nanda\.vscode\New folder\envs\my\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 402, in load_build
    Unpickler.load_build(self)
  File "C:\Users\nanda\.vscode\New folder\envs\my\lib\pickle.py", line 1717, in load_build
    setstate(state)
  File "sklearn\\tree\\_tree.pyx", line 865, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__setstate__
  File "sklearn\\tree\\_tree.pyx", line 1571, in sklearn.tree._tree._check_node_ndarray
ValueError: node array from the pickle has an incompatible dtype:
- expected: {'names': ['left_child', 'right_child', 'feature', 'threshold', 'impurity', 'n_node_samples', 'weighted_n_node_samples', 'missing_go_to_left'], 'formats': ['<i8', '<i8', '<i8', '<f8', '<f8', '<i8', '<f8', 'u1'], 'offsets': [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56], 'itemsize': 64}
- got     : [('left_child', '<i8'), ('right_child''', '<i8'), ('feature', '<i8'), ('''threshold''', '<f8'), ('impurity', '<f8'), ('n_node_samples', '<i8'), ('weighted_n_node_samples', '<f8')]
```

i tried running the code in vs code but the above error arised

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide generalized debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)

Comment: Your issue is that the file 'dtm.joblib', which contains your pretrained model, has different content than expoected. Seems like only the 'names' part of the dictionary is included, instead of also 'formats', 'offsets' and 'itemsize'.